# How to find element via partial text within table with multiple rows and cells per row?

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

My goal is to basically get Selenium to click the "Disable" link that is  hidden within the table amongst many rows and cells multiple times.

I'm reading from an Excel spreadsheet to get the values of "P#####" (it's always the 2nd ) to loop. These are all partial texts though. The "randomwords" after the P#####, I don't know. So I need to be able to find the element by partial text which I think I accomplished in my own code but I'm unable to verify if that part is working.

There's about 1000 rows and I don't need to access them all. The IDs for the a href tag have random numbers after them that do not correspond to the P##### value.

Here's what the HTML looks like (not real):

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1.</td>
    <td>P12345 randomwordshere</td>
    <td>..</td>
    <td>..</td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li>..</li>
        <li>..</li>
        <li><a id="disable_###" href="link">Disable</a></li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2.</td>
    <td>P23456 otherrandomwords</td>
    <td>..</td>
    <td>..</td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li>..</li>
        <li>..</li>
        <li><a id="disable_###" href="link">Disable</a></li>
      </ul>
  </tr>
  <tr>..</tr>
  <tr>..</tr>
  <tr>..</tr>
  <tr>..</tr>
  <tr>..</tr>
  <tr>..</tr>
  <tr>..</tr>
</tbody>
```

Here's what part of my python code looks like so far with no success.

```
for x in range(0, num_rows):
  value = str(sheet.cell(x, 0))
  pcode = value[7:len(value) - 1]
  browser.implicitly_wait(10)
  browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '" + pcode + "')]")
  browser.find_element_by_xpath("//td/ul/li[contains(@id, 'disable')]").click() #this part is definitely wrong
```

So how do I find each of the Disable links within the row of the same P#### value that I have?

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: @AmosEgel Sorry that wasn't clear. How do I find each Disable link based off each of the P#### values that I have? They're in the same rows but I don't know how to do anything based off that.

Comment: Just an observation but your HTML is not well formed (it is invalid) this could be messing up your XPATH can you try in on well formed HTML?

Comment: @Dan-Dev The HTML that I put in there is just an example of what I'm looking at, I don't have any control over the HTML so that's what I have to deal with and work around.

Comment: If your reading the HTML from an Excel spreadsheet can you pass it through HTML tidy first? But my point was to help debug this if we know it is due to invalid HTML then we know where to start.

Comment: Have you tried browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text()

Comment: or even find_element_by_link_text()

Comment: @Dan-Dev how do I do that if I don't know which Disable link I need?

Comment: Does the id of the disable link have any relation to the P#s? e.g. is the id "disable_12345" when the P# is P12345? A link to the page you are dealing with would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the pcode and then do a following to find the disable. The way you are currently doing it is throwing away the first find_element.

Something along these lines should work (it worked for me). I think for python it's following-sibling.

`(//*[contains(., 'P')]/following::li/a[contains(@id, 'disable')])[i]`

Put your pcode where the 'P' is and then just increment through the results with a for loop, that's what the index of '[i]' is at the end.

*Obviously you will need to make your own edits as we don't have the full code to give a complete answer, but this should give you a start down the right path.*

Comment: pcode = value[7:len(value) - 1] 
 for i in range(0,1200):
            browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(., '" + pcode + "')]/following::li/a[contains(@id, 'disable')])[i](//*[contains(., '" + pcode + "')]/following::li/a[contains(@id, 'disable')]")[i].click()


It says the expression is illegal. I'm getting the pcode from the spreadsheet so you can ignore that first line. I'm not sure if this for loop if what you had in mind, I'm not familiar with that i at the end of the statement. But I also had to add some " " for syntax.

Sorry, trying to fix the formatting right now

Comment: Why are you doubling the xpath?  it should just be  `browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//*[contains(., '" + pcode + "')]/following::li/a[contains(@id, 'disable')])[i].click()")`

Comment: Open up a browser console and see if you can find the element via this `(//*[contains(., 'P')]/following::li/a[contains(@id, 'disable')])`.  You'll see it shows multiple finds.  This is what the increment is for.

Comment: Oops, I must have pasted that twice, my mistake. I fixed it and this is the new error: 
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //*[contains(., 'P000001 - Database')]/following::li/a[contains(@id, 'disable')]

Comment: Open up a browser console and see if you can find the element via this `(//*[contains(., 'P000001 - Database')]/following::li/a[contains(@id, 'disable')])`

Comment: Says 862 matches. So it looks like the xpath is correct, would you have any idea why it doesn't work in python though?

Comment: Try for i in range(1, 1200)?  You can't have a 0 index.  Also you might want to see if you can get a count of all the matches and put that as the larger range value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using XPath.

```
//td[contains(.,'P12345')]//following::a[starts-with(@id,'disable_')]
```

This XPath looks for a `TD` that contains your P# and then looks for the first `A` tag that has an ID that starts with 'disable_'.

You will want to replace 'P12345' with the value from Excel each loop. This will return ALL disable links. As long as you use `find_element()`, it will always return the first one which is the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Use below pattern to find the tr which constains the pcode:

`//tr[td[contains(text(), 'Database')]]`   assume the pcode here is 'Database'

Then find the 'Disable' link from the found tr as below:

`//tr[td[contains(text(), 'Database')]]//a[text()='Disable']`

Try below code:

```
for x in range(0, num_rows):
  value = str(sheet.cell(x, 0))
  pcode = value[7:len(value) - 1]
  browser.implicitly_wait(10)
  browser.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[td[contains(text(), '" + pcode + "')]]//a[text()='Disable']").click()
```